# gulp: как перекомпилировать только изменённые файлы, разбитые на несколько файлов (на примере pug)

Tags: gulp, pug, gulp-watch

В приведённой ниже файловой подсистеме файл `partial1.pug` является частью `test1.pug` (включён в него через `include`), а файл `partial2.pug` - полностью самостоятельный:

pug

test1.pug

test2.pug

partials

partial1.pug

**test1.pug**

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title Test 1
  body
    h1 Test 1
    include partials/partial1.pug
```

Вот, какого результата я хочу в результате написания gulp-таска:

- отредактировали `test1.pug`  → скомпилировался **только** `test1.pug`
- отредактировали `partial1.pug`→ скомпилировался **только** `test1.pug`
- отредактировался `test2.pug`  → скомпилировался **только** `test2.pug`

В следующем gulp-таске, при редактировании одного из `partial1.pug` или `partial2.pug` каждый раз компилироваться будут оба:

```
gulp.task('pug', () => {
  return gulp.src('pug/*.pug')
  .pipe(pug())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
});
```

Пытаясь решить эту проблему, мы можем добавить `{since: gulp.lastRun('pug')}`:

```
gulp.task('pug', () => {
  return gulp.src('pug/*.pug', {since: gulp.lastRun('pug')})
  .pipe(pug())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
});
```

Тогда инкрементальной сборке (с использованием `gulp-watch`) начиная со второго, автоматического запуска таска `pug` будет скомпилирован только отредактированный файл. Однако, если мы отредактируем `partial1.pug`, то ничего откомпилировано не будет (оно и понятно: `test1.pug` же не менялся).

Изменение glob-паттерна на `'pug/**/*.pug'` тоже желаемого результата не даст:

- Если установить такой паттерн для `gulp-watch`, то после редактирования `partial1.pug` запуск таска pug произойдёт, но `{since: gulp.lastRun('pug')}` не пропустит файл `test1.pug`.
- Если установить такой паттерн для самого таска pug, то `partial1.pug` будет компилироваться в отдельный файл, чего нам не нужно.

Как же быть?

Comment: gnu make нигде в проекте не используется? знаю решение для него

Comment: @Total Pusher, нет... Никогда не слышал про это даже..

Answer (score 1):

```js
var pathJsChangeFile = '';
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(paths.pathWeb + '/js/**/*.js', ['jsWathc']).on('change', function(event) {
        pathJsChangeFile = event.path;
        console.log('File ' + event.path + ' was ' + event.type + ', running tasks...');
    });
});

gulp.task('jsWathc', function() {
    return gulp.src(pathJsChangeFile)
        ..//
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.pathDist + dest + ''))
})

не идельное решение но работает
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Не могли бы Вы дать краткий комментарий к своему решению?

Answer (score 1):

```js
gulp.task('pug', () => {
  return gulp.src('pug/*.pug')
    /* https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-newer */
    .pipe(newer({
      dest: 'dist',
      extra: './app/{components,helpers,layouts,partials}/**/*.*'
    }))
    .pipe(pug())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
});
```

или [плагин Emitty](https://github.com/mrmlnc/emitty)